# Procurando um grupo de registros duplicados

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Eu tenho a tabela abaixo:

```
declare @order table (idOrder int, altcode varchar(17) )

insert into @order values (1,'11111111111')   
insert into @order values (1,'22222222222')    
insert into @order values (1,'33333333333')  
insert into @order values (1,'44444444444')  

insert into @order values (2,'72374949491')  
insert into @order values (2, '11111111111')  
insert into @order values (2,'66194701273')   
insert into @order values (2,'22222222222')  
insert into @order values (2,'33333333333') 

insert into @order values (3,'87548758844')  
insert into @order values (3, '11111111111')  
insert into @order values (3,'734821919192')  
insert into @order values (3,'22222222222')  
insert into @order values (3,'33333333333')       
insert into @order values (3,'74912817837')  
insert into @order values (3,'67198191782') 

insert into @order values (4,'77777777777')  
insert into @order values (4, '11111111111')  
insert into @order values (4,'771904749189')  
insert into @order values (4,'33333333333')  
insert into @order values (4,'88888888888')    
insert into @order values (4,'99999999999')  

insert into @order values (5,'88888888888')  
insert into @order values (5,'781843741091')  
insert into @order values (5,'33333333333')  
insert into @order values (5,'99999999999')  
insert into @order values (5,'77777777777')
```

Eu preciso escrever uma consulta para encontrar todos as ordens e altcodes que qualquer combinação de 3 altcodes se repetem em ordens diferentes.

Por exemplo: Uma consulta que funciona com a tabela acima deve encontrar isto:

```
O grupo de altcodes:
'11111111111'
'22222222222'
'33333333333'
são encontrados nas orders: 1, 2, 3

O grupo de altcodes:
'77777777777'
'88888888888'
'99999999999'
são encontrados nas orders: 4,5 

O grupo de altcodes:
'33333333333'
'88888888888'
'99999999999'
são encontrados nas orders: 4,5 

O grupo de altcodes:
'33333333333',
'77777777777',
'88888888888'
são encontrados nas orders: 4,5 

O grupo de altcodes:
'33333333333',
'77777777777',
'99999999999'
são encontrados nas orders: 4,5
```

Estou tendo dificuldade em pensar em uma consulta ou algoritmo com um cursor que resolva isso. Eu acho que deve haver algum comando fácil para resolver isso, mas eu não posso ver isso.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma `query` que conta as ocorrências na tabela em que a referência está dentro dos valores propostos, utilizando a cláusula `COUNT`. Depois disso basta usar a cláusula `HAVING` para verificar se o número de ocorrências é igual ao número de referências, como por exemplo:

```
SELECT o.idOrder
  FROM @order o
 WHERE o.altcode IN ('77777777777', '88888888888', '99999999999') 
 GROUP BY o.idOrder
HAVING COUNT(1) = 3
```

Que irá resultado em `4` e `5`, ou:

```
SELECT o.idOrder
  FROM @order o
 WHERE o.altcode IN ('11111111111', '22222222222', '33333333333') 
 GROUP BY o.idOrder
HAVING COUNT(1) = 3
```

Que irá resultado em `1`, `2` e `3`.

---

No exemplo abaixo criei a tabela `ocorrencias` para substituir `@order`. Crie a função baseada na `query` acima:

```
CREATE FUNCTION buscar_ocorrencias(@altcode1 VARCHAR(17),
                                   @altcode2 VARCHAR(17),
                                   @altcode3 VARCHAR(17))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @lista NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @lista = ISNULL(@lista + ', ', '') +  CAST(o.idOrder AS VARCHAR)
      FROM ocorrencia o
     WHERE o.altcode IN (@altcode1, @altcode2, @altcode3) 
     GROUP BY o.idOrder
     HAVING COUNT(1) = 3;

    RETURN @lista;
END;
```

E depois a utilize da seguinte forma:

```
WITH posicao AS (
  SELECT o.altcode,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.altcode) AS posicao
    FROM ocorrencia o
   GROUP BY o.altcode
), combinacao AS (
  SELECT p1.altcode AS altcode1,
         p2.altcode AS altcode2,
         p3.altcode AS altcode3,
         dbo.buscar_ocorrencias(p1.altcode, p2.altcode, p3.altcode) AS ocorrencias
    FROM posicao p1
   INNER JOIN posicao p2
      ON p2.posicao > p1.posicao
   INNER JOIN posicao p3
      ON p3.posicao > p2.posicao
)
SELECT c.altcode1,
       c.altcode2,
       c.altcode3,
       ocorrencias
  FROM combinacao c
 WHERE ocorrencias IS NOT NULL
```

Na primeira [`cte`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) atribuímos uma posição a cada registro único, enquanto na segunda vinculamos cada registro aos seus subsequentes, gerando assim a combinação (sem repetir) de todas as linhas. Dentro dessa combinação realizamos a consulta na função citada anteriormente. Com esse resultado precisamos apenas filtrar os resultados não nulos, ou seja, que tem grupos em comum.

**Observação:** A partir da versão 2017 do `SQL Server` você pode usar a função `STRING_AGG` ao invés de criar a função `buscar_ocorrencias`.

> [`STRING_AGG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Concatena os valores das expressões de cadeia de caracteres e coloca os valores de separador entre eles. O separador não é adicionado ao final da cadeia de caracteres.

Comment: Os altcodes são dinâmicos, não posso especifica-los, são milhares. A solução precisa ser dinâminca. O problema é justamente esse, achar qualquer combinação de 3 altcodes que se repetem em ordens diferentes.

Comment: @skyzoserver você não vai informar quais você quer saber os grupos?

Comment: Não, os grupos são dinâmicos. Qualquer ocorrência de 3 altcodes em ordens diferentes devem ser retornados na pesquisa, essa é a dificuldade.

Comment: @skyzoserver alterei para funcionar da forma que você pediu, porém devo te advertir que gerar combinações nas condições que você citou (milhares de altcodes) deve ser pouco performático e vai levar um tempo para a `query` ser resolvida.

Comment: Sensacional! Você é um mito! Era exatamente o que eu precisava!

Comment: Creio que não consigo aceitá-la pois está dizendo que não tenho reputação...

Answer (score 1):

É possível assim, talvez seja mais rápido e mais prático:

```
SELECT idOrder, altcode from @ORDER where altcode in (
    SELECT ALTCODE FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS QT, ALTCODE FROM @ORDER
            GROUP BY ALTCODE 
            ) a WHERE QT > 1 )
    GROUP BY idorder, altcode
ORDER BY idorder
```

Comment: Mas aí não tem os agrupamentos de 3 em 3 que o OP pediu